# Excel startup processes

Tags: excel, time, process, startup

What are the processes going on when we open any excel workbook. It takes some time to open. I want to know how can we check what process are going on and how much time they take to get processed while the file is being opened.
How can we postpone or suppress those processes.

[image: Snapshot of excel while opening]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This doesn't seem to be a programming question or, if it is, it is unclear what technologies/languages you are attempting to use. Consider posting to a different site (perhaps [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)). Also see [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The following contributes to the excel file loading (excluding Native excel files)

1. Add-ins (sometimes add-in check for updates at start-up and takes time): To disable go to Files > Options > Add-ins > under manage disable the ones that you don't need
2. Links/Formula to external files in Server :
   More on this can be found [here](https://www.excelefficiency.com/fix-slow-excel-files/#:%7E:text=The%20biggest%20reason%20for%20slow,take%20too%20long%20to%20calculate.&text=This%20means%20your%20file%20won,Calculation%20%3E%20Calculation%20Options%20%3E%20Manual.)
3. Data (Size) of the file being opened :
   It is very important to understand that excel is not a full fledged database. Avoid dumping unnecessary information and manage databases separately in Access or Sql